# Twitter gem with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, tweets

I'm trying to incorporate the Twitter gem into my project(http://sferik.github.io/twitter/). I have it installed and I have the client created with my own configuration codes and access keys in them in an initialiser in my project as follows:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

I also have a controller set up for it and a view. When I try to use it however it doesn't seem to work.
My controller has the following:

```
@tweets = $client.mentions_timeline
```

While my view is trying to access these tweets by calling:

```
  <% @client.user_timeline do |tweet| %>
    <%= tweet.text %>
  <% end %>
```

However Im presented with the error: Unable to verify your credentials. I have the app created on Twitter and the codes are correct.
I'm wondering how do I fix this or how can I get Twitter integrated properly?

Comment: And you added your key , secret and tokens in that initalizer (instead of hte dummy text) ?

Comment: yeah I have and it still gives me that error.

Comment: Where did you put `client = Twitter::REST::Client.new`? Which file?

Comment: I'm after getting it working by initialising the client in the application controller, thanks !